# iPhone app compatibility with iPad - Must I Support x2 Mode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, ipad

I have witten an iPhone game using Quartz 2d. It works fine all devices including the iPad, however when you use the "x2" magnifier on the iPad the game has major display problems.

Do I have to make my game work with the x2 magnifier on the iPad - or can I somehow specify that it does not work with x2 mode ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**2.10 iPhone apps must also run on iPad without modification, at iPhone resolution, and at 2X iPhone3GS resolution**

from [App Store Review Guidelines](http://stadium.weblogsinc.com/engadget/files/app-store-guidelines.pdf)

Comment: Thanks. I think the issue is the scale that the iPad x2 mode is using. I am using "responds to selector" to set the scale. I wonder what value to iPad x2 mode uses ?

Answer (score 3):

Apps ought to work seamlessly, without changes, in the iPad 2x mode. Since you're getting display problems in that mode, it indicates there's a bug that only manifests itself in 2x mode. I would try to track down what that bug is, it's just waiting to bite you in 1x mode I expect.