# iPad Content Scale Factor x2 for iPhone application

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiimageview, scale, retina-display

I'm hoping to recursively change every single View in my application to use the iPhone 4 graphics, and change the content scale factor to 2.0, such that it's the zoomed in version of my iPhone application on the iPad by default.

Currently, the iPad starts out in x1 Zoom, which is the 320x480 pixel version displayed on the 1024x768 real estate of the iPad, where the powers that be have declared that they're too cheap to actually invest in an iPad app, instead requesting that we have the application use iPhone retina graphics with a default content scale factor of 2.0

Upon googling and searching stackoverflow it seems my query is unique, though some questions are sort of similar such as -> [Problem adapting scale factor for iPad x2 compatibility mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3873868/problem-adapting-scale-factor-for-ipad-x2-compatibility-mode)

And the best way to go about doing this remains undocumented, so I hope to implement this 'hack' so to speak in the best most succinct way possible.

If anyone has done this before, please share the code, otherwise I will update this with my own answer once I've figured it out.

Comment: Lame that they're too cheap to do a real iPad app.  What are you going to do in the eventuality that iPad will have a retina-like display? Sounds like a hidden time-bomb that may produce a bigger problem than it may have initially been worth.

Comment: Yep, I recommend alternative options, explained time estimates, issues, recommendations whenever I had the opportunity to actually just build iPad views, and it was resisted, enough for me to accept that it's their way or the highway. Basically, I'm running a pre/post comilation script that replaces the @2x.png's with the *.png images, and puts them back again post build.

Comment: Scrap the previous comment, it makes no difference on resolution as the iOS is scaling the window not the subviews, so everything is treated as 320x480...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Answer: THIS CANNOT BE DONE.

The iPad will treat the screen as 480x320, even at 2x, so even if you change the contentScaleFactor appropriately and force it to use @2x.png images, you won't get any better resolution.

This is built into the iphone Operating system, only the Jailbroken iPads can get around this. Which isn't an option to consider.

It's easier to just duplicate the target for iPad, and realign the nib files appropriately, and make the app a Universal App.

It's a daft idea, and even if Apple change this in future SDK releases, it won't be backward compatible which again isn't an option, at least for our development team.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do it rules out using nib files.

If you create your views in code, you can easily use conditional code (`[[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom]`) and based on that set the scale for the `UIView` elements.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm needing to take the nib files into account, so I may need to intercept the UIView initWithCoder method and make changes to all of the UIImageViews from xyz.png to xyz@2x.png